# Unable to set NowPlayingInfo to nil

Tags: ios, swift, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I am unable to reset NowPlayingInfo to nil, using this code in runtime:

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nil        
    if MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo != nil {
        print("3PX: There was a problem Removing nowPlayInfo")
    } else {
        print("3PX: nowPlayInfo Removed")
    }
```

but if I set a breakpoint on the first line then it works correctly. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -->

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try? audioSession.setActive(false, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [:]
```